# How to loop through the ajax function and retrieve result from database by looping order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a website. In this website i have to show the temperature of each sensor devices. [Image of the sensor details](https://snag.gy/jPqlFo.jpg). I'm getting these sensor information by looping through php. Now, i want to make them live. Which means i want to show the live temperature rate for each devices. I have done some coding part without looping the whole device via ajax call. I'm storing the device information in ul li tags. [Image of ul li](https://snag.gy/LyBRo0.jpg). Here you can see each li represents own 'device-code' and 'site-page' (in this case 'site-page' is same). Now I want to loop each li and retrieve temperature value according to each 'device-code' and 'site-page'.

And this is my jquery/ajax function :

```
    setInterval(function() {

    var lis = $('#ul-devices li').length;

    for(x=0; x<lis; x++){

    var site_device_code = $('#ul-devices li:nth-child('+ (x+1) +')').data('device-code');
    var sitePageId = $('#ul-devices li:nth-child('+ (x+1) +')').data('site-page')

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sitefunction.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { 'sitePageId' : sitePageId, 'device_code' : site_device_code },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(sitePageId);
                console.log(site_device_code);              
                console.log(data.temp_value);
            }
        });
    }

}, 1000);
```

Now this is my php function(sitefunction.php) :

```
require_once 'inc/core/init.php';
$db = DB::getInstance();
if(Input::get('sitePageId') && Input::get('device_code')) {

    $sitePageId = Input::get('sitePageId');
    $device_code = Input::get('device_code');

    $sensorsInfo = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM `device_info` WHERE `site_code` = {$sitePageId} AND `device_code` = {$device_code}");

    while($sensor = $sensors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $temp_value = $sensor->value;
        $last_updated = $sensor->last_updated;
    };

    $result = array(
            'temp_value' => $temp_value,
            'last_updated' => $last_updated
        );

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Here $db represents the database connection class.

Now the problem is when i run this code the result is, [the result image](https://snag.gy/B3jW9l.jpg) here you can see following values is repeating,

```
1 (sitePageId)
8627334 (last li tag's device_code)
undefined (data.temp_value)
```

i want the result should be like this (in console),

```
1 (sitePageId)
312169 (device_code)
34 (data.temp_value)

1
13618979
255

1
312890
33.25

1
8627813
41

1
8627334
23
```

If anyone knew how to solve this, Please help me sort it out.

**Updated**

this is my jquery code:

```
    setInterval(function() {

    var lis = $('#ul-devices li').length;

    for(x=0; x<lis; x++){

    var site_device_code = $('#ul-devices li:nth-child('+ (x+1) +')').data('device-code');
    var sitePageId = $('#ul-devices li:nth-child('+ (x+1) +')').data('site-page')

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sitefunction.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { 'sitePageId' : sitePageId, 'device_code' : site_device_code },
            success:function(data){
                for( var d in data ){
                    console.log(d.site_code); //site_code,device_code,value are database field names
                    console.log(d.device_code);             
                    console.log(d.value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}, 1000);
```

This is my php code:

```
require_once 'inc/core/init.php';
$db = DB::getInstance();
if(Input::get('sitePageId') && Input::get('device_code')) {

    $sitePageId = Input::get('sitePageId');
    $device_code = Input::get('device_code');

    $sensors = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM `device_info` WHERE `site_code` = {$sitePageId} AND `device_code` = {$device_code}");

    $rows = array();

    while($sensor = $sensors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $sensor;
    };

    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

This is my database table :
[image: database table]

**Updated result**

[image: updated result]

Comment: There is no `site_code` field in that table that I can see.... unless it's cut off.  There is a `owner_user_code` though...

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix yes it has been cut off.. do you want me to update it?

Comment: No, but it's my bed time, like I mentioned do `console.log(data)` just inside the ajax sucess, `success:function(data){ console.log(data); ..` that should output an array with nested objects with those fields as the properties `[{device_code: 31269, ... },{...}]`, then work from there.  If it's empty then you don't have any results from the query.  Inside the loop you should have just one row as `d` like this `{device_code: 31269, ... }`  Then you would access it like `d.device_code` which would equal 31269 in this example.

Comment: Sure, good luck..  This part is wrong too `var site_device_code = $('#ul-devices li:nth-child('+ (x+1) +')').data('device-code');`  nth child is gonna give you duplicates, so if nth is 1 you get ever 1 child if its 2 you get every other child if its 3 you get every third child.  But for 2 you already got them with 1 and for 3 you got them with 1 and every 3rd 2, or every 6th one.  you'd be better off pulling them all and making one ajax call.

Comment: The undefined is `temp_value`, right. I only see a field as `value` unless that is cut off, so it's `d.value` instead...  These will all match what is in the table, the table columns are the json properties and they should all match up...

Comment: So what is undefined now?  you'll probably get repeat data because of what I said about using `nth` with an increment.  it will be like row 1,2,3,4,5,6 then 2,4,6 then 3,6..  so you will get 6 3x and 4 2x and 2 2x, etc.  You might not because of your where clause, I don't know what the values of all that is, but regardless it's not efficient to make so many request in a loop.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix i have updated result page in the original question. and if you say `nth` increment will the problem, then how get the value of each li tag? do u any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a multi-dimensional return array, currently you are returning only data for the last record.  you'll need to change this

```
 while($sensor = $sensors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    //these variables are overwritten on each itteration
    $temp_value = $sensor->value;
    $last_updated = $sensor->last_updated;
};

//Those 2 vars only contain the last row now...
//results here is a single dimensional array of only one row.
$result = array(
        'temp_value' => $temp_value,
        'last_updated' => $last_updated
    );
```

Each loop in the above `while` overwrites those two variables, so at the end of the loop you only get the last record in the DB result set, mainly because you access the variables outside of the loop.  So you need to change it to:

```
 $rows = array();
 while($row = $sensors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $rows[] = $row;
};

 echo json_encode($rows);
```

By using `FETCH_ASSOC` you don't need to convert it to an array.  Your array should look something like this ( after the loop )

```
$rows = array(
      array( 'sitePageId'=>1, 'device_code' => 312169, 'temp_value' => 34 ),
       array( 'sitePageId'=>1, 'device_code' => 4445455, 'temp_value' => 27),
   .... 
);
```

Instead of this ( original data )

```
   $results = array( 'sitePageId'=>1, 'device_code' => 312169, 'temp_value' => 34 );
```

Then in the JS success callback you can do something like this:

```
   success:function(data){
        for( var d in data ){
            console.log(d.sitePageId);
            console.log(d.device_code);              
            console.log(d.temp_value);
       }
    }
```

Because your Json will be like this

```
    [
       { sitePageId:1, device_code:312169, temp_value:34 },
       { sitePageId:1, device_code:4445455, temp_value:27},
        .... 
   ]
```

Provided the query returns these fields `sitePageId, device_code, temp_value`  I think you don't have `sitePageId` in there but you get the Idea I am sure.  Basically just unwrap the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working I have changed the coding as you mentioned. The result is 'undefined' 
[my jquery code](https://snag.gy/PErG0c.jpg)
[my php code](https://snag.gy/hO0HfU.jpg)
[my database](https://snag.gy/4D2CT3.jpg)
[my result](https://snag.gy/RiPMQI.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I'm not fond of external image links, can you update the original question.  Also this is all just from the head, and I see this `site_device_code` is actually `device_code`  So you have to play with it a bit, but you wont get it to work with a single row ( as originally ), that much you can be sure of...

Comment: after the `success:function(data){` part add `console.log(data);` and then work from there.  Also you could do `console.log(d);` just inside the for loop to see what the properties are.  The first one should give you the multi-dimensional json, the second a single row.

Comment: @Thanoo - what is this `The result is 'undefined' ` specifically.  Also you dont need the `};` at the close of the `while` loop.

Comment: after adding  this part `success:function(data){ for( var d in data ){ console.log(d.site_code);       console.log(d.device_code);  
console.log(d.value);
}`  in console it says 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to loop on controls solve your problem

```
$('#ul-devices li').each(function(i, n){
  console.log("device=" + $(n).data("device-code") + ", page=" + $(n).data("site-page"));
});
```

Comment: How will that solve the issue of returning only one row from php?